# Array comparison and re-order in PHP

Tags: php, arrays

Let's say I Have two arrays.

```
$arr1 = ['A','B','C','D'];

$arr2 = ['C','D'];
```

now compare two arrays.if there is no match for value of $arr1 in $arr2 then index is left empty.
for the above arrays output should be:

```
$arr3 = ['','','C','D']
```

I tried array_search() function.But couldn't achieve desired output.

Any possible solutions?

Comment: Did you try `array_diff()`?

Comment: I would just simply `foreach $arr1 as $key => $value` through it and check if `in_array($value, $arr2)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `foreach` with `in_array` and `array_push` like:

```
$arr1 = ['A','B','C','D'];
$arr2 = ['C','D'];
$arr3 = [];

foreach($arr1 as $value){
    $arr3[] = (in_array($value, $arr2)) ? $value : '';
}

print_r($arr3);

/*
Result
Array
(
    [0] => 
    [1] => 
    [2] => C
    [3] => D
) */
```

`Foreach` the first array then test with `in_array` if exist, if `true` push into array 3 `else` push empty value

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following function. In the following code, the function search_in_array return true and false based on the searching within the 2nd array. So you can push the empty or searched value in final array.

```
<?php
$arr1 = array('A','B','C','D');
$arr2 = array('C','D');
$arr3 = array();
function search_in_array ($value, $array)
{
    for ($i=0; $i<count($array); $i++)
    {
        if ($value == $array[$i])
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

for ($i=0; $i<count($arr1); $i++)
{
    $value = $arr1[$i];
    $result = search_in_array ($value, $arr2);
    if ($result)
    {
        array_push ($arr3, $value);
    }
    else
    {
        array_push ($arr3, '');
    }
}
print_array($arr3);
?>
```

Comment: You are creating a function that does exactly the same thing as using `in_array`

Comment: Sometimes the simplest solution is the right one :)